# @Viewchild with multiple autocomplete ids in angular 7

Tags: angular

```
@ViewChild('search1', {static: false})
@ViewChild('search', {static: false})
```

Im trying to display these 2 ids from the viewchild but only one of them is actually displaying. im trying to display two different auto-complete inputs on the same page for agm google maps one is the actually input ontop of a map and the other one is just a address search input

html

```
<div class="col-md-5">
 <div class="form-group Search-text"> <input type="text" class="form-control border-btm" id="place" #search [formControl]="searchControl" placeholder="physical address">
                    </div>
                </div>

<div class="form-group Search-text">
<input type="text" class="form-control border-btm" id="auto-place" #search1 [formControl]="searchControl"placeholder="physical address">
      </div>
```

ts

```
  @ViewChild('search1', {static: false})
  @ViewChild('search', {static: false})



  ngOnInit() {
    // set google maps defaults
    this.zoom = 16;
    this.latitude = -26.051738;
    this.longitude = 28.0244903;
    // create search FormControl
    this.searchControl = new FormControl();
    // set current position
    this.setCurrentPosition();
    // load Places Autocomplete
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        this.searchElementRef.nativeElement,
        {
          types: [],
          componentRestrictions: { country: 'ZA' }
        }
      );
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          // get the place result
          const place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
          // verify result

          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            return;
          }
          // set latitude, longitude and zoom
          this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
          this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
          this.zoom = 16;
        });
      });
    });
  }

  private setCurrentPosition() {
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        this.zoom = 8;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you show code, it would be very helpful to community to help you

Comment: Add the html and ts code